# How to open folders from Total Commander search results one by one in right pane

Tags: search, total-commander

I do a file search in Total Commander, and then show the search results in my left pane using 'Feed to listbox'. Many of the results are folders.

Is there a way to open a folder from the left list in the right pane, **with the search results in the left pane staying intact/unchanged**? I don't want to repeat the search every time.

Example use case: I search for 'temp', I then want to empty all the folders named 'temp'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Right Arrow while the cursor is over the folder to open in the right pane.

From Total Commander 8.51a Help/Keyboard:

> CTRL+left/right: Open directory/archive and display it in the target window. If the cursor is not on a directory name, or the other panel is active, then the current directory is displayed instead.